# Adding CSS class to one option of select not working in FF5

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have the following html code

```
<select id="WageBenifits_PayType" name="WageBenifits.PayType">
    <option class="selectOption" value="" selected="selected">Please Select Value</option>
    <option value="COM">COM - COMMISSIONS AND BONUS PAY</option>
    <option value="HOL">HOL - HOLIDAY PAY</option>
</select>
```

With the following css

```
.selectOption {
   color: #999;
   font-style : italic;
   text-transform: none; 
   font-variant: small-caps; }
```

My problem is that this works as expected in IE8, but in FF5, adding the css class "selectOption" doesn't affect the styling.  In Firebug, I can see that the class has been selected and applied to the item.  However, it doesn't change the displayed text in the select dropdown control.  It is changed in the dropdown list, but not in the display line.

See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/vRZCr/

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, running Firefox 5.0.

Comment: Never use IE as a reference for how things should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, CSS issue aside, this is actually what you want:

```
<select id="WageBenifits_PayType" name="WageBenifits.PayType">
    <option disabled="disabled">Please Select Value</option>
    <option value="COM">COM - COMMISSIONS AND BONUS PAY</option>
    <option value="HOL">HOL - HOLIDAY PAY</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/vRZCr/1/

Answer (score 1):

What's shown in the display line in Firefox is not actually the option; it's just the text from the option.  You can test this by injecting elements with styling as kids of the `<option>` and seeing the styling from those not show up in the display line.

Some browsers hack things in where some (but not all!) of an `<option>`'s styles are applied to the display line.  We've been considering doing something like that in Gecko, but given the complete lack of browser interop here we'd rather have a spec for how things should behave before rocking the boat with changes to behavior.